# Как найти экранные координаты маркера карты Google

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Скажите, пожалуйста, как в обработчике событий маркера/кластера карты Google (например события mouseover) получить координаты маркера/кластера относительно окна браузера?
В документации сказано, что класс OverlayView содержит методы для преобразования координат в координаты на экране. Но как это сделать я не понимаю.
Получить экранные координаты маркера я хочу в этом блоке:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) {

    });
```